# Where to add guard config information of zfc-rbac?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfc-rbac

I am following [this](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/02.%20Quick%20Start.md#adding-a-guard) guide to add Zfc-Rbac in my application. But I can't figure out where to put this configuration information.

Application\config\application.config.files

or Application\modules\modulename\config\module.config.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also put it in a global config file, ie `application/config/autoload/zfcrbac.global.php`

Answer (score 0):

Either in application/module or application/vendor, place the config inside the ModuleName/config/module.config.php

Also make sure you have added the ZfcRbac to the application module list

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'ZfcRbac',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule'
```